# Image in hugo markdown not showing

Tags: image, r-markdown, hugo

I have a markdown page processed by Hugo.

I'm trying to show an image named `application_list_complete.png`, located in the same directory as the .md page.
Here are some of my attempts. None of them show the image, just the text "aaa" .

```
![](application_list_complete.png "title")
![aaa](application_list_complete.png "title")
![](./application_list_complete.png "title")
![aaa](./application_list_complete.png "title")
![]("./application_list_complete.png" "title")
![aaa]("./application_list_complete.png" "title")
![]("./application_list_complete.png" )
![aaa]("./application_list_complete.png")
```

(I also tried with other images)

Comment: I think that for this to work you need to use a leaf bundle, i.e. the `.md` file must be named `index.md` and it, as well as the `.png` file, need to be in a bundle directory. I wrote about Hugo bundles in https://www.ii.com/hugo-bundles/

Answer (score 2):

Hugo natively uses the static folder for assets when building.
You are currently in the context of markdown, I assume you are using Goldmark.

If you want to have assets in the same folder:
https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/

You want to make a page bundle.

This isn't the simplest process, so you need to ask yourself "Do I want to completely change my site so I can do this? Or just to start with, should I just put my images where hugo natively wants my images?"

If so, page bundles and assets is the way to go, but this is no longer markdown, but using hugo's page resources functions with is using the GO template type codes {{}} and so forth.

(from this link: https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/)

> content
> └── post
> ├── first-post
> │   ├── images
> │   │   ├── a.jpg
> │   │   ├── b.jpg
> │   │   └── c.jpg
> │   ├── index.md (root of page bundle)
> │   ├── latest.html
> │   ├── manual.json
> │   ├── notice.md
> │   ├── office.mp3
> │   ├── pocket.mp4
> │   ├── rating.pdf
> │   └── safety.txt
> └── second-post
> └── index.md (root of page bundle)

Then in the template:

.Resources.Match "images/a*"

Again, this is no longer markdown, but HuGo proper.

The deeper question to ask is, why do you need the image in bundles? What problem are you trying to solve?

The actual answer is: Because Hugo doesn't work like that, but if you can elaborate, we can help I'm sure.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm OK with putting images in a separate static directory, or whatever is required. What is weird is that putting images in the same directory as the .md file works in other places. I guess this has to do with the configuration files, which I did not create but inherited from prior projects. I'll have to take a deeper plunge into Hugo.

Comment: Absolutely Francis. If you made your repo available we could help more and the Hugo discourse is SUPER helpful. But, it could be those other areas are set-up as page bundles, but you would have to read up on that subject.

Comment: Hmm, really sad - in my opinion this is a no go. Hugo/Markdown should pick images from Markdown-Subfolders.

Comment: Mike Mitterer - to ensure your comment does not provide false information for anyone searching (As your comment and supposition are unfortunately not valid) Hugo (which isn't connected to Markdown so Hugo/markdown doesn't make sense as a comment) can. It's a different bundle type - ergo my comment.